# Storing another control value in a field of DetailsView Insert Interface

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, detailsview

I have an asp.net program.

Here I want to keep Insert Facility of the Details view. But in the interface I want to keep the 'UserName' attribute of the new Record as fixed and same as the UserName of the Logged in user. I also want to check it on Server side whether it corresponds to the logged in user's username.

How can I achieve this functionality.

I have made the BoundField ReadOnly. But I can't find anything else suitable for this functionality.

Comment: What datasource are you using and can I see the code?

Comment: @Simua I figured out part of the functionality. I just had to remove the field from Grid view fields and from Bound Fields of details view. And I added a textbox as control field in the data source to give form id. Problem is, I don't know how safe it is to do this. I have just made the textbox hidden but hackers can easily change the content of the textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep Insert Facility of the Details view"? I will recommend you create an InsertParameter then in the code behind, you set the parameter default value as Context.User.Identity.Name. I can provide a sample code if you want.

Comment: @Simua It would be great if you could give that example as an answer. I meant to say I want users to be able to insert in the database. But at the same time they shouldn't be able to modify username or other field like form_id which are specific to the user or the form they are currently working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .aspx do the following:

```asp
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" OnInserting="SqlDataSource1_Inserting">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Username" />
        //Place other parameters here
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In your code behind:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Username"].DefaultValue = Context.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I have been stuck on this question for ages :)